# How to add a plugin to tracecompass(an eclipse plugin project)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-tracecompass

I found [this](https://github.com/jonahkichwacoders/tracecompass-experiments/tree/master/com.kichwacoders.tracecompass.callstack) plugin which I want to try out. I am not familiar with eclipse. The repository says to add it as a plugin to [tracecompass](https://github.com/tracecompass).I am using an already built binary of tracecompass. Is it possible to add a plugin to an already built eclipse project or do I have to add the plugin and then rebuild it from source? In any way, how do I add the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to import the plugin.

### Clone the repository outside of eclipse and import

1. `git clone https://github.com/jonahkichwacoders/tracecompass-experiments.git`
2. Select "File -> Import..."
3. Select "General -> Existing Projects into Workspace"
4. Next to "Select root directory" click "Browse..."
5. Navigate to the directory where you git clone'd the project earlier.

### Clone and import from the Git perspective

1. Select "Window -> Perspective -> Other ..."
2. Select "Git"
3. Select "Clone a Git repository" from the "Git repositories" view
4. Select "Clone URI"
5. Paste `https://github.com/jonahkichwacoders/tracecompass-experiments.git` in the URI field and press "next"
6. Select the branch and finish